# Rails validation for nested attributes in just one especific model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, nested-attributes

I am new regarding validations of nested attributes for an especific model and I am finding it quite impossible to solve.

I have a `Pharmacy model` as per below:

```
class Pharmacy < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :address

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :address

  validates :address, presence: true

  validate :address_postcode_town

  def address_postcode_town
   errors.add(:'address.postcode', 'Postcode can't be blank') if address&.postcode.blank?
   errors.add(:'address.town', "Town can't be blank") if address&.town.blank?
  end
end
```

I also have an `Address model` that currently look like this:

```
class Address < ActiveRecord::Base

validates :first_line, presence: true
end
```

As you can see, address validates presence of first line, and I need to add validation on postcode for `Pharmacy`, and here comes the part when I get lost.

I need validation of postcode, which is an attribute of `Address`, only for my `Pharmacy` and not for my `Order`

I tried to add `validates :postcode, presence: true` in my `Address` model but then it is a requirement for Order as well, which I don't want to happen.

I have also tried a `before_validation` in my `Pharmacy` model but not sure if that works, as the view is not showing the `postcode can't be blank` message:

```
before_validation :ensure_address_has_a_value

def ensure_address_has_a_value
  return false if address.blank?
  !address.postcode.blank? || !address.city.blank?
end
```

How can I add validation for nested attributes only in one model, leaving the other as they are?

I have managed to create a custom validation that works, but now the view does not recognise `postcode` nor `town` as a required attributes, therefore id does not show the error message. It just renders the form again.

`params` are available in the `PharmacyController` and my view looks like below:

```
**simple_form_for :pharmacy goes here**
<%= f.simple_fields_for :address do |a|%>
  <%= a.input :first_line, label: t('.first_line'), wrapper_html: {class: 'form-row'}%>
  <%= a.input :second_line, label: t('.second_line'), wrapper_html: {class: 'form-row'}%>
  <%= a.input :postcode, label: t('.postcode'), wrapper_html: {class: 'form-row'} %>
  <%= a.input :town, label: t('.town'), wrapper_html: {class: 'form-row'} %>
```

This did not help me [Validation for nested attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16074689/validation-for-nested-attributes)

Can anyone shed some light on this? Many thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

This is the first result on google search that might help http://homeonrails.com/2012/10/validating-nested-associations-in-rails/

Comment: Thanks, I have tried that but the `reject_if`, if I am not wrong, relies on the values of the model where it is set rather than on the values that come from the associated model. I need to accept the attributes if they fulfil a condition rather than if the model where they need to be accepted has an especific feature.

Comment: I believe you can do something like

`accepts_nested_attributes_for :address reject_if: proc { |attributes| attributes['zipcode'].blank? }`

in your `Pharmacy` model.

Comment: I have managed to create a custom validation that works, but now the view does not recognise `postcode` and `town`  as a required attributes, therefore id does not show the error message. It just renders the form again

Comment: According to simple form  usage documentation here https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form#usage 

```
By default all inputs are required. When the form object includes ActiveModel::Validations (which, for example, happens with Active Record models), fields are required only when there is presence validation. Otherwise, Simple Form will mark fields as optional.
```

Comment: That brings me one step closer, I have added `required: true` to my fields so now they are shown as so in the page, added `<%= f.full_error :town, wrapper_html: {class: 'error'}  %>` and the error is visible! Now I just need to fix the css that is not showing for some reason....
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Adapted from https://www.homeonrails.com/2012/10/validating-nested-associations-in-rails/

```rb
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  OFFICES_COUNT_MINIMUM = 1

  has_many :offices

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :offices, allow_destroy: true

  validates :name, presence: true
  validate :check_offices_number

  private

  def check_offices_number
    unless offices.count >= OFFICES_COUNT_MINIMUM
      errors.add(:base, :offices_too_short, count: OFFICES_COUNT_MINIMUM)
    end
  end
end
```